# What is wrong with my redirect?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, lamp, haproxy

I need haproxy to redirect product.company.com to company.com/about/product

```
acl newproduct hdr(host) –i product.company.com
redirect location http://company.com/about/product if newproduct
```

I know I'm hitting the server, but it never redirects.  I've tried hdr_beg(host) product, and that didn't work.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is correct.  haproxy didn't like the location of the redirect.